# Invalid argument error from open when reading data from a windows program in perl

Tags: perl, runtime-error

I am an intermediate user that has been pressed into service to work with routines that monitor program use by getting license manager status reports.
I am using perl on a server that is running Windows Server 2019 Standard V 1809

I am presently having a problem with a new program (based on ones that work) which produces an `“Invalid argument”` error when it runs the line to get the status.

The lines in the program that I am having trouble with are:

```perl
# $command1 = "c:\\Cadence\\LicenseManager\\lmutil.exe lmstat -a -c `c:\\Cadence\\LicenseManager\\license.dat |";
$command1 = '"C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\bin\lmutil" lmstat -a -c "C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\innovmet.lic"';

print "Read license status - >$command1<\n\n";
open(STATUS, $command1) || die "Couldn't run $command1: $!\n";
```

The commented version of the `$command1` assignment works from a previous program.
The uncommented version produces `"C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\bin\lmutil" lmstat -a -c "C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\innovmet.lic"` which runs perfectly as a command from a command prompt.
The big difference that I can see is that I had to use `‘` so that I could get the quote marks needed to handle the spaces in the directory names.  I did not get to specify the directory names.
The uncommented version does not have the  pipe in the command.  I wanted to be sure that this was not the cause of the problem and it cannot run from the command line with it.

The output that I get from this part of the code is:

> Read license status - >"C:/Program Files/InnovMetric/PolyWorks MS License Server 2022/bin/lmutil" lmstat -a -c "C:/Program Files/InnovMetric/PolyWorks MS License Server 2022/innovmet.lic"<
>
> Couldn't run "C:/Program Files/InnovMetric/PolyWorks MS License Server 2022/bin/lmutil" lmstat -a -c "C:/Program Files/InnovMetric/PolyWorks MS License Server 2022/innovmet.lic": Invalid argument

Anyone have ideas why perl doesn’t like the command line I am asking it to run?

Comment: Without the pipe on the end of the file name, Perl is not trying to run a command. Instead, it is trying to open a file named `"C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\bin\lmutil" lmstat -a -c "C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\innovmet.lic"`. Your "Invalid argument" is coming from the Windows file I/O machinery, but I have no clue why you are getting that error rather than "No such file or directory", or possibly "File name too long." Note that as posted your code fragment does not compile. Is the terminal back tick spurious?

Comment: I updated the code so it would compile -- as @user20284150 says, ther eis a trailing single quote

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the code to compile in the original question, I get this when I run it

```
>perl.exe try.pl
Read license status - >"C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\bin\lmutil" lmstat -a -c "C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\innovmet.lic"<

Couldn't run "C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\bin\lmutil" lmstat -a -c "C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\innovmet.lic": Invalid argument
```

That matches what you have. As @user20284150 already mentioned, passing `open` a filename without a trailing `|` means it will attempt to open the **file** `"C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\bin\lmutil" lmstat -a -c "C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\innovmet.lic"`. That **file** doesn't exist, thus the error. No idea why it gives the unhelpful error though - would have expected it to say `No such file or directory`.

To show the distinction, here is a quick demo. Firstly doing the equivalent of what you did and run the `open` without the trailing `|`

```perl
use strict ;
use warnings;

# Not no trailing "|" in the command
my $command1 = 'perl -v';

print "Read license status - >$command1<\n\n";
open(STATUS, $command1) || die "Couldn't run '$command1': $!\n";

while(<STATUS>)
{
    print "GOT --  $_";
}
```

running gives

```
>perl.exe try.pl
Read license status - >perl -v<

Couldn't run 'perl -v': No such file or directory
```

That gives a useful error

Now the same code, but with the trailing `|` included

```perl
use strict ;
use warnings;

# note trailing "|" this time
my $command1 = 'perl -v |';

print "Read license status - >$command1<\n\n";
open(STATUS, $command1) || die "Couldn't run '$command1': $!\n";

while(<STATUS>)
{
    print "GOT --  $_";
}
```

that gives this output

```
>perl.exe try.pl
Read license status - >perl -v |<

GOT --  
GOT --  This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
GOT --
GOT --  Copyright 1987-2021, Larry Wall
GOT --
GOT --  Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GOT --  GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.
GOT --
GOT --  Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
GOT --  this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
GOT --  Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
GOT --
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to open a file named `"C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\bin\lmutil" lmstat -a -c "C:\Program Files\InnovMetric\PolyWorks MS License Server 2022\innovmet.lic"` for reading. There's no such file. It's not even a legal file name, thus the `Invalid argument` error message.

The correct approach:

```perl
my $cmd = '...';

open( my $pipe, "-|", $cmd )
   or die( "Can't launch cmd: $!\n" );

...

close( $pipe );
die( "Error closing pipe: $!\n"                   ) if $? == -1;
die( "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"  ) if $? >> 8;
```

(@pmqs suggests `open( PIPE, "$cmd |" )` instead of `open( my $pipe, "-|", $cmd )`, but using `open` with only two arguments is archaïc, and using a global variable for the file handle is a bad practice.)

---

For example,

```perl
use v5.14;
use warnings;

my $cmd = 'perl -v';

open( my $pipe, "-|", $cmd )
   or die( "Can't launch cmd: $!\n" );

while ( <$pipe> ) {
   chomp;
   say "[$_]";
}

close( $pipe );
die( "Error closing pipe: $!\n"                   ) if $? == -1;
die( "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"  ) if $? >> 8;
```

```
>75747203.pl
[]
[This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread]
[]
[Copyright 1987-2021, Larry Wall]
[]
[Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the]
[GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.]
[]
[Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on]
[this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the]
[Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.]
[]
```